# Data Cleaning/Data Replacement in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm attempting to clean up some data I'm using by replacing extreme values with `NA`. The data I'm trying to modify is part of a larger data set consisting of 110 variables (both numerical and categorical) that pertain to flight information during the month of January, 2017. The code I've been trying to run is fairly simple and works when I apply it to the whole dataset. However, I want to simply change the data for one variable, not all. This is what I have:

```
flightdataJan2017[flightdataJan2017$DEP_DELAY >= 240] <- NA
```

The error this gives is:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, flightdataJan2017$DEP_DELAY >= 240,  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

I'm not certain as to what's causing this issue, because when I remove the "subsection" argument (meaning when I get rid of `$DEP_DELAY`), the code runs properly. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a comma: `flightdataJan2017[flightdataJan2017$DEP_DELAY>=240, ]<-NA` so that your indexing applies to the rows and then selects all columns.

Comment: Adding the comma did not resolve the issue, it's still the same.

Comment: flightdataJan2017$DEP_DELAY[flightdataJan2017$DEP_DELAY>=240]<-NA

Comment: Thanks, silly thing to forget.